# Advanced SUMIFS to count over two range criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an employer booking sheet that I use in my business and I want to calculate how many people have been booked for interviews within a certain employer and year and I cant use a Pivot chart. I can use the following formula to work out how many people seen in a year but I also need to filter by employer.

My table:

```
**************************************************
Date of Interview * Employer * Candidates Booked *
**************************************************
21/10/2015        * XRM Inc. * 23                *
01/08/2016        * PRS Inc. * 3                 *
18/07/2014        * PPS Inc. * 18                *
15/01/2016        * XRM Inc. * 10                *
21/10/2015        * SRT Inc. * 42                *
**************************************************
```

Using the below forumla gives me 13 as expected for 2016 but I want to filter that down to 'Employer' as well

```
=SUMIF(Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Date of Interview],"<="&DATE("2016",12,31), Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Candidates Booked])
```

I tried using `SUMIFS` but it didn't work for me so I don't know if there is another approach to this? Any help would be great!

EDIT:

This is the `SUMIFS` I tried, but it just gives me an error

```
=SUMIFS(Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Date of Interview],"<="&DATE("2016",12,31), Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Candidates Booked], Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Employer], "XRM Inc")
```

Edit2:

This also throws up an error:

```
=SUMIFS(Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Employer], "XRM Inc", Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Candidates Booked],Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Date of Interview],"<="&DATE("2016",12,31))
```

Comment: then use SUMIFS() with an `S` that will allow you to have more than one criteria.

Comment: Hi, ive added the SUMIFS but it just gives me an error

Comment: The order of SUMIFS() is different, you need to put the range that is to be summed first not last with the criteria following.

Comment: Hi, i've also tried that and it throws up another error. See Edit2

Comment: the column you are summing is `Recruitment_Days_Datasheet[Candidates Booked]` it needs to be the first criterion then the others.